# The Wind Blows as the Wheel Wills

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, story, geography

The Wheel of Time turns, and Ages come and pass, leaving memories that become legend. 
Legend and names fades to myth, and even myth is long forgotten when the Age that gave it birth comes again. 
In one Age, called the 2nd Age by some, an Age yet to come, an Age long past, a wind rose. 
The wind was not the beginning. 
There are neither beginnings nor endings to the turning of the Wheel of Time. But it was a beginning.

South and eastward the wind blew, 
warm, dry and strong.
Dehydrated, tired and weary
Egwene pushed herself to her limits, Rand was sure of it.
Tangled up in underbrush and vines, but she would come.

North and westward the wind blew,
South lay a land known by the travelling people.
Rand was waiting, counting minutes and hours.
Was that Perrin?

Rand felt a ripple and turned, the wind had turned. Now from the East, from <s>Kary</s> Qari.

His mother. Had she been there all the time?
Up, over the mountains to the north, in the city where the wind blew from?
"Kary", he shouted, but to no avail
At last, he understood. No one would come.
Born again, but all alone!

---

A good tracker can track yesterday's wind. Can you?

**Hint 1:**

> If this puzzle sends you to Monaco then I think you might need a new courier.

**Hint 2:**

> Tracking the wind shouldn't be too hard when you know where it's going.

**Hint 3:**

> Maybe it would have been easier if I had spelled his mother's name differently. I suggest you use Kari or Qari instead. Let's pretend it was just a typo in the poem.

**Hint 4:**

> You start in a city whose name is derived from [insert language here] "place of the winds" and end in a city whose name *might* be derived from [insert language here] "a place where wind is pounding".

**Hint 5:**

> It should be possible to draw a simple polygonal chain / path on a map.

**Hint 6:**

> You can disregard the first paragraph. And a lot of the other stuff is simply scenery.

**Hint 7:**

> A big tips this time: Gareth McCaughan's guess that Kary/Kari/Qari is supposed to be read from the east is correct.

**Final hint:**

> Relevance of hints:
>  Hint 1: refers to two "things" that have one thing in common. What is it, and how can it help?
>  Hint 2: The direction of the wind is relevant (essential) in all paragraphs
>  Hint 3: Assume it says Qari. (It's written differently because "names fade"
>  Hint 4: The starting *city* could not have been derived from the original puzzle, only the area. The end city could be derived from the puzzle.
>  Hint 5: Using Hint 2, you can draw lines on a map. (Directions are only approximate. South-east can for instance be very close to east (like 95 degrees))
>  Hint 6: The only (partly) relevant part of the first paragraph is "names fade". But you could solve this puzzle without this knowledge, so you can disregard that paragraph. It's to set the scene, so to say.
>  Hint 7: If you read Kari from east to west. What do you think will help in other paragraphs?

<sub>No in-universe knowledge is needed for this puzzle.</sub>

Comment: Oh hey there ...

Comment: My mother's name is **Kari**, not Kary. Is that a typo or a deliberate clue?

Comment: Burn my soul, mayhaps this do be another Rand? Also, no comment ;-)

Comment: Blood and ashes, I probably should have written Rand's mother's name differently after all @Randal'Thor. It was deliberate, but in hindsight I shouldn't have written it that way. Let's pretend it was a typo.

Comment: I wonder whether this wants the [enigmatic-puzzle] tag. A couple of elements seem pretty clear, but I'm having trouble figuring out (1) exactly what we're being asked to do, (2) if it's something like "figure out where Rand is", with how much precision, (3) whether all the WoT stuff is just there to be picturesque or whether it somehow contains information (which it could even if we don't need "in-universe knowledge"), and (4) which bits _are_ WoT stuff (hence maybe picturesque-only) and which _aren't_ (hence presumably significant).

Comment: E.g., would it be functionally the same puzzle if it just said: "I'm not sure where I am. The wind blows from the southeast, warm, dry and strong. The wind blows from the northwest. South lies a land known for the travelling people. The wind blows from the east, from Qari. Up and over the mountains, to the north, is the city where the wind blows from."? Or would it be broken by the absence of some of the stuff that I've omitted because it _looks_ like WoT-thematic fluff? (Other names? Underbrush and vines? Minutes and hours? That opening bit?)

Comment: I can put it like this: knowledge of the wheel of Time won't help you in any way. If you can track the wind, you'll figure out approximately where Rand is, though not very precisely. The puzzle would be broken if I had changed it with what you wrote.

Comment: I think I can place him to within, say, a few hundred miles. But I haven't yet used anything that's different between the actual puzzle and my stripped-down version, so clearly I'm missing a thing or two.

Comment: You might actually have the correct solution... I guess it's possible to solve it in your rewritten way, but you've definitely made it harder for yourself. Please post it as an answer.

Comment: I'll stare at it for a while longer to see whether I can figure out how to make it easier for myself using the other details of the question as actually written...

Comment: Have you understood the meaning of the first hint, and how it can make solving this easier?

Comment: I hadn't. But I just looked at it again, and maybe I do after all.

Comment: Ah, I think I have just understood why the WoT theme.

Comment: Better late than never. New hint added.

Answer (score 3):

**Partial and uncertain answer**

I'm not sure exactly *how* partial, because I'm not sure exactly what the question is asking nor what parts of it are clues to be picked up as opposed to scene-setting. I'm *fairly* confident that I have the right overall theme, but there are enough things I can't fit in that I won't be astonished if I turn out to be barking up quite the wrong tree.

I think we are looking here at

> the history of the Apple Macintosh and its typefaces, with particular emphasis on the "classical" pre-OS-X Mac.

The windy city is

> CHICAGO.

Kary/Kari/Qari is

> not, as I first guessed, Iraq read "from the east", but [Susan Kare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Susan_Kare), designer of many early Apple Macintosh fonts and icons. ... Though her name is pronounced like "care", which gives me pause.

I think the land to the south known to the travelling people *might* be

> Egypt (the word "gypsy" is a corruption of "Egyptian", though of course that word's deprecated these days and the people in question were never actually from Egypt), whose capital is CAIRO, whose name is shared with another Kare font on the Mac. (A dingbat font, whose characters are symbols rather than letters.) I'm not very convinced by any of this, though.

I confess myself baffled by the south-and-eastward / north-and-westward blowing of the wind. My best guess is that

> it's describing the geographical migration of the Mac's system font names. We start in *Chicago*. We head south and east to *Geneva* and more generally to Switzerland for which *Helvetica* is named. And then north and west again to *San Francisco*. But why the wind ends up blowing from the east, apparently from Chicago, I'm not sure.

The "Second Age" is

> presumably that of the original Apple Macintosh (after the 8-bit micros like the Apple ][, but before today's OS X)

and I guess "born again, but all alone" may be

> referring to the Mac OS X era, in which all those Susan Kare creations are abandoned and largely forgotten, which is why Rand's mother is never coming. -- Although apparently *no one* is coming, so maybe I haven't understood this right yet. Or maybe "all alone" is a reference to the fact that these days Apple have pretty much settled on their San Francisco font for everything.

Hint 1 is

> pointing at the *Monaco* and *Courier* typefaces (the former is another Susan Kare creation for Apple, the latter not).

Some things I don't understand (maybe some of them are scenery rather than clues?):

- The underbrush and vines.
- The warm/dry/strong/dehydrated/tired/weary business.
- Why Rand is counting minutes and hours.
- The wind directions. (I have a half-baked theory above, but it doesn't really explain why the wind is eventually coming from the east. I can kinda fudge it, but not convincingly.)
- Some of the ordering. (E.g., I have what may be an explanation for the wind blowing "north and westward", and what may be an explanation for the southern land known by the travelling people, but I don't see why they appear side by side in the way they do.)

That's a lot of holes. Maybe the above is all nonsense. If so, then my best theory is

> that Kary/Kari/Qari *is* Iraq read "from the east" after all, the land known to the travelling people is Egypt or maaaaybe Israel (for obvious reasons), and Rand is somewhere in the Middle East or maybe in the Mediterranean Sea. But I can't get much else to fit with that.

Comment: Wow, this is well done, +1 for effort, but unfortunately very wrong. Your original guess regarding Kari is correct. Knowing that might help you solve the rest.

Comment: Ha! I did say I thought it might be all wrong :-).

Comment: @CG. Would you like to indicate whether I have the correct points of reference in hint 1? (Of course it's fine if you wouldn't.)

Comment: You are pointing at two things. Those two have one thing in common that makes them different from most other types...

Comment: Oh yes, so they do. Interesting. At this point I have several pieces but haven't yet figured out how to put them together. (Quite possibly someone else will do it before I do. I'm in the middle of a bunch of other things...)

Comment: New hint added.

Comment: FTR: "Your original guess regarding Kari is correct. Knowing that might help you solve the rest." is the biggest hint I can give without giving away the entire puzzle.